# Why does make $(abspath path) concatenate result with current directory?

Tags: makefile

As part of a makefile recipe I have:

```
@echo SOMEDIR:$(SOMEDIR)
@echo abspath:$(abspath $(SOMEDIR))
```

Which produces:

```
SOMEDIR:D:/one/two/three/../../four
abspath:D:/P4_sandbox/depot/ssg/embedded/industrial/MotorControl/ReferenceDesigns/DriveOnChip_SingleIPOneEach_SoC_FFT/software/CVSX_DS5/APP_RD/D:/one/four
```

I expected to get:

```
SOMEDIR:D:/one/two/three/../../four
abspath:D:/one/four
```

Why is abspath concatenating its result to the value of $(CURDIR), and how do I stop it?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  You should probably ask on the make-w32@gnu.org mailing list, which deals specifically with running GNU make on Windows. Be sure you provide all the details there that you omitted here, such as which version of GNU make you're using, which version of Windows, how you built make (cygwin?  Mingw32?  MSVC project files?  Batch file?), etc.  Someone there should be able to address this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, abspath is just not happy with drive-letter designations. Try it again with the D: removed. If removing D: beforehand is not possible for you, you're going to have to write a gmake macro (wrapper). Without having gmake at hand, here's an exercise in FP, defining three macros so that $(ABSPATH $(mypathvar)) works ...

```
_FLIP = $2 $1
_ABSPATH = $(subst \ ,:, $(strip $2 $(abspath $1)))
ABSPATH = $(_ABSPATH $(FLIP $(subst :, ,$1))))
```

Comment: Thank you! Removing D: beforehand (and adding at back afterwards works a treat and is much nicer than my own workaround.

Comment: @Mischa what is $2 and $1.

Comment: Sorry, what was I drinking ... $1,$2,... are the arguments to a user-defined make macro. They aren't evaluated till the macro is invoked. But I must have been flipping among too many Lang's that day. Should have written: ABSPATH = $(call _ABSPATH, ... ) Humble apologies; never type code on a phone .

Answer (score 1):

That's what `abspath` does. It creates an absolute path. That means it must be anchored at the root. `abspath` is not simply `canonicalize path`.

You will need to `subst` that off or something to get the behaviour you want I imagine.

Comment: I prefer to take the answer that it's a bug. <CURDIR>/D:/<expected path> isn't a valid absolute path. The second : breaks other recipes you see.

Comment: Ah, I see the added Windows drive spec complexity now. I'm not sure I think this is a bug as-such but it certainly looks unintended.

Comment: Whether it's a bug or not depends completely on where you got this version of GNU make and what environment you're using it in, as I mentioned in my comment above.  If it's a cygwin version then it's probably not a bug: cygwin uses POSIX paths, not Windows paths.  If it's a native Windows version (mingw32 or msvc) then probably it is a bug.